# NoMethodError: undefined method `each_value' when parsing YAML array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have a simple YAML array with values like this

```
%YAML 1.1
---

-
  - 'd7744c3878'
  - '80705686'
-
  - 'c349b086b1'
  - '80705686'
-
  - '516e25d139'
  - '95203563'
```

I try the following code to iterate on them and add them to the database.

```
YAML.load_file("db/tokens.yml").each_value do |yml_token|

    token = Token.find_or_create_by_token_origin(
           token_origin: yml_token[0],
           token_value: yml_token[1]) 

end
```

But I get a `NoMethodError: undefined method each_value for #<String:0x000000059ab7f8>`
 error when try to run the code.

Any idea what is causing this?

UPDATE:

Using `Psych.load` as suggested below I also get a `SyntaxError: db/gallery_tokens.yml:1: unknown type of %string
%YAML 1.1` error.

```
require "psych"
Psych.load("db/tokens.yml").each do |yml_token|

    token = Token.find_or_create_by_token_origin(
           token_origin: yml_token[0],
           token_value: yml_token[1]) 

end
```

Comment: What do you get if you inspect `YAML.load_file("db/tokens.yml")` ?

Comment: I get the whole array YAML array.

Comment: `each_value` does not exist for `Array`s, this is used for `Hash`es.

Comment: @oldergod What should I use instead?

Comment: You need to call `Psych.load_file` if you're going to parse a file on the harddrive.

Comment: Using `Psych.load_file` returns `NoMethodError: undefined method `load_file' for Psych:Module`

Comment: I'm using `psych (1.2.1)`; what version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that the declaration at the top, "%YAML 1.1", is causing problems.

No error:

```
require "yaml"
YAML.load("---\n\n-\n  - 'd7744c3878'\n  - '80705686'").each
=> #<Enumerator: [["d7744c3878", "80705686"]]:each>
```

Error:

```
YAML.load("%YAML 1.1\n---\n\n-\n  - 'd7744c3878'\n  - '80705686'").each
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "%YAML 1.1 ---\n- - 'd7744c3878' - '80705686'":String
        from (irb):4
        from /Users/modify/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/irb:17:in `<main>'
```

Here I'm using ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i386-darwin9.8.0]. I also note that in an unmodified environment, [`#each_value`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-each_value) is available for a `Hash` but not an `Array` (@oldergod).

It looks like Psych, which is the default YAML interepreter in later versions of Ruby, can handle the `%YAML 1.1` directive:

```
require "psych"
Psych.load("%YAML 1.1\n---\n\n-\n  - 'd7744c3878'\n  - '80705686'").each
=> #<Enumerator: [["d7744c3878", "80705686"]]:each>
```

Possible alternatives to using Psych directly would be to switch to a later version of Ruby or to strip the `%YAML 1.1` header from the file.

Comment: So, what should I use instead?

Comment: @Martin: It looks like there are several options -- see my edits.

Comment: Using psych I get this error `SyntaxError: db/tokens.yml:1: unknown type of %string
%YAML 1.1
   ^
`

Comment: @Martin: what version of Psych and Ruby are you using?

Comment: ruby 1.9.2, how can I see Psych version? I don't see it on `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: @Martin: either `gem list psych` or `bundle exec gem list psych`, depending on whether there is a Gemfile or not.

Comment: Only says `*** LOCAL GEMS ***`

Comment: @Martin: Is there a `Gemfile`?

Comment: It is not on Gemfile, seems to come by default. If I try to add it to Gemfile when launching server I get an error: `/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@site/gems/psych-1.3.4/lib/psych.rb:96: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@site/gems/psych-1.3.4/lib/psych.rb:99: warning: already initialized constant LIBYAML_VERSION
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@site/gems/psych-1.3.4/lib/psych.rb:203:in `parse': wrong number of arguments(2 for 1) (ArgumentError)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21361/discussion-between-eric-walker-and-martin)